# SQL How to target a specific part of a string

Tags: sql, sql-like

I have a varchar(11) table and all its entries will look something like this.

```
Table
123456-7890
101112-1314
```

I need to find everything that has

```
??12??-????
```

(? Being any character)
How would I do this?

Edit: Thanks bill!!

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myfield LIKE '__12%'
```

Is what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 4):

```
WHERE YourColumn LIKE '__12__-____'
```

The `_` means "match any single character"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using ANSI SQL, what you're looking for is '_':

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myField LIKE '__12__-____'
```

For most Microsoft products, the question mark, as you used it is, is correct.